# Rails 5.1 strong parameters deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

## I'm working on using `form_with` in Rails 5.1.3 & Ruby 2.3.0

The best documentation I've found is here

#### [Rails Github Repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/21cd5b3031b0c022439a88cb750c1e00cd07f1e3/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb) on line 533, but it's still unclear to me.

```
# The parameters in the forms are accessible in controllers according to
# their name nesting. So inputs named +title+ and <tt>post[title]</tt> are
# accessible as <tt>params[:title]</tt> and <tt>params[:post][:title]</tt>
# respectively.
```

## Code:

```
# friendships_controller.rb
...
private

def friendship_params
  params.require(:friendship).permit(:user_id, :id)
end

# Works
def destroy
  Friendship.remove_friend(current_user.id, params[:id].to_i)
end

# Doesn't work
def destroy
  Friendship.remove_friend(friendship_params[:user_id].to_i, friendship_params[:id].to_i)
end


# form_with 
<%= form_with model: Friendship, 
      url: user_friendship_path(
        user_id: current_user.id
        id: other_user.id, 
      ), method: :delete do |f| %>

  <button class='button'></button>

<% end %>
```

I know the naming is a little confusing, I still haven't figured out how to get `form_with` to map correctly to the route I need.
`friendships#destroy` located at path
`/users/:user_id/friendships/:id(.:format)`

```
resources :users do
  resources :friendships
end
```

## Error Message

```
Started DELETE "/users/1/friendships/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-02 03:21:40 +0700
Processing by FriendshipsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"fWnYwpNDItctgg3q/TYIXy5VRO55nwQRINCCykMsDPAFBfwJKjMZ1dneNbg    5yFNHaQP+lXR4ViTje6mK+dCmVg==", "user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT     $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Friendship Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE     "friendships"."friend_id" = $1 AND "friendships"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY     "friendships"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["friend_id", 1], ["user_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  DELETE FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."id" = $1  [["id",     499]]
  Friendship Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE     "friendships"."friend_id" = $1 AND "friendships"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY     "friendships"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["friend_id", 8], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."id" = $1  [["id",     498]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:     friendship):

app/controllers/friendships_controller.rb:40:in `friendship_params'
app/controllers/friendships_controller.rb:22:in `destroy'
```

Maybe I shouldn't say it doesn't work, the behavior is how I expect with or without the `friendship_params`. However, the server logs returning a `400 Bad Request` is a red flag to me.

#### Thanks for any suggestions in advance~!

Comment: You are requiring `friendship` but not passing it as a param

Comment: Isn't that what `model: Friendship` is doing on the `form_with`? Sorry if that's a dumb question... I haven't gotten a chance to get familiar with `form_with` yet. I knew I felt like the problem would be there... but I'm just not sure how to do it correctly because documentation is limited.

Answer (score 1):

The route is a nested resource, so you should provide two arguments to the path.  you also need to provide the scope to give it the "friendship" key in the params.

```
<%= form_with scope: :friendship, url: user_friendship_path(current_user, other_user), method: :delete do |f| %>

  <button class='button'></button>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it was a mistake or not but when you remove the `id` from the `user_friendships_path` Rails complains `No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"friendships", :user_id=>1}, missing required keys: [:id]`

Answer (score 1):

This code is little bit confusing, I suggesting the way for simple like change your route like below

```
resources :users do
  resources :friendships
end
```

Change to

```
resources :users
resources :friendships
```

and on the view

```
<%= link_to "Remove Friend", friendship_path(friend_id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure"}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
```

and finally the controller

```
def destroy
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.where(friend_id: params[:id]).first
    @friendship.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Friend was removed"
    redirect_to(my_friends_path)
end
```

Hope to help

Comment: Dude, haha I originally had it set up this way.

I agree, it's definitely simpler this way, but I felt like a friendship naturally corresponds to a user, so it SHOULD be a nested route... 

What are you thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the arguments to the `form_with` don't pass the actually parameters to the **key** `Friendship`, we have to pass them manually within the body of the form.

```
<%= form_with model: Friendship, url: 
  user_friendship_path(
    current_user, other_user
  ), method: :delete do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: other_user.id %>

  <button class='button'></button>

<% end %>
```